# ¿Excepciones con las anotaciones en Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Tengo un programa que muestra los campos de una BBDD con un simple `System.out.println();` Esta parte funciona bien, muestra los campos perfectamente por pantalla

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sesion.openSession();

        System.out.println("=================");
        System.out.println("DATOS DEL DEPARTAMENTO 10.");

        Departamentos dep = new Departamentos();
        dep = (Departamentos) session.load(Departamentos.class, (byte)10);

        System.out.println("Nombre dep: " + dep.getDnombre());
        System.out.println("Localidad: " + dep.getLoc());

        System.out.println("=================");
        System.out.println("EMPLEADOS DEL DEPARTAMENTO 10.");

        Set<Empleados> listaemple = dep.getEmpleadoses();
        Iterator<Empleados> it = listaemple.iterator();

        System.out.printf("Número de empleados: %d %n", listaemple.size());

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Empleados emple = it.next();
            System.out.printf("%s * %.2f %n", emple.getApellido(), emple.getSalario());
        }
        System.out.println("==============================");
        session.close();
        System.exit(0);

    }
//Esto se muestra por pantalla (Que es lo que debe mostrar)
=================
DATOS DEL DEPARTAMENTO 10.
Nombre dep: CONTABILIDAD
Localidad: SEVILLA
=================
EMPLEADOS DEL DEPARTAMENTO 10.
Número de empleados: 1 
BATUECAS * 698,70 
==============================
```

Pero muestra esta expeción también, la cual no encuentro el motivo

```
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: tuputamadre/hibernate.hbm.xml
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: tuputamadre/Departamentos.hbm.xml
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
INFO: HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: tuputamadre/Empleados.hbm.xml
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prueba]
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root}
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
ene 23, 2019 11:59:25 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
ene 23, 2019 11:59:26 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
ene 23, 2019 11:59:26 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
ene 23, 2019 11:59:26 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: No es una excepción, solo tienes INFO y dos WARNINGS. Lo que estás viendo es el logger de hibernate. No creo que tenga mucha importancia para lo que estás haciendo ¿no?

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev no causa problema para la ejecución desde luego pero me gustaría que no saliera por pantalla

Comment: Entonces puedes configurar el logger para hibernate a nivel ERROR. Con esto ya no te debe pintar nada en la consola.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev como se puede hacer eso?

Comment: Pues no lo sé exactamente. Tu estas ejecutando una clase con main. Debes crear un fichero log4j.properties o log4j.xml y dentro meter la configuración del logger. Supongo que si colocas el fichero en el root de tu proyecto debe funcionar. Entonces hibernate usará la configuración del logger y voila, no debe pintar mas trazas. Algo así, pero yo no suelo hacer aplicaciones de escritorio.